# Creating a mongoDB backup/dump on remote server via local CMD/Shell

Tags: mongodb

I hope you can help me.

It is a question that was asked before, but I have tried all solutions, and simply cannot get it right.

I have spend quite some time researching before posting this question. I have looked at the official MongoDB documents and many other blogs.

How can I make a DB backup/dump remotely, as well as restore that dump locally?

This is what I have thus far:

Running this from a new CMD prompt shell:

```
C:\Users\Admin>mongodump --host 10.13.9.210 -d C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin --port 29039 --out /backup/mongodump-2015-11-13
```

I get this error:

```
2015-11-13T10:26:41.371+0200    error parsing command line options: expected argument for flag `/o, /out', but got option `/backup/mongodump-2015-11-13'
2015-11-13T10:26:41.371+0200    try 'mongodump --help' for more information
```

Secondly, how will I be able to restore this backup locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux and Mac, arguments for command-line tools normally have one of these two formats:
`--option1 value1` or  `-o value1`.

On Windows, the standard is different:
`/option1 value1` or `/o value1`.

`mongo`, `mongodump` and other command-line MongoDB programs actually preserve the Linux way of passing arguments. But the Windows `cmd.exe` shell will still recognize the character `/` as a beginning of a command-line option.

Also, in UNIX systems, `/` is used to separated parts of a file system path, e.g. `/data/db`. On Windows, `\` is used instead: `C:\Data\DB`.

Your problem is this part of the command: `--out /backup/mongodump-2015-11-13`. You kept the backup path in the UNIX format, and `/` was recognized as a starting character of a command-line option.

You should specify a real file system path on your hard drive instead. For example:

```
--out C:\backup\mongodump-2015-11-13
```

Also, your data path (`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin`) contains a space. Because of the space, `cmd.exe` will treat `C:\Program` and `Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin` as separate parameters. To prevent this, surround the path with quotes:

```
-d "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin"
```

And as a final note, do **not** use the `bin` folder to store your data files (as you seem to be doing judging by the path you're passing to `-d`).